# How to prove this graph is not bipartite and thus has no hamilton cycle

Tags: bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-path

[image: graph G]

I already know that this graph has a hamilton path (2⇒1⇒8⇒7⇒6⇒10⇒4⇒3⇒11⇒5⇒9) but how can I prove from this that this is NOT a bipartite graph? and why does and how does it prove there isn't a Hamilton cycle?

Comment: Prove its not?  How about proving it *is*.  $\{1,3,5,7,10\}$ is one part and $\{2,4,6,8,9,11\}$ is the other part.

Comment: As for why proving that it *is* bipartite proves there is not a hamiltonian cycle... because a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no cycles with an odd number of vertices.  There being a cycle involving all of the vertices $1,2,\dots,11$ would contradict that.

Comment: I didn't notice the bipartite, thank you for pointing it out